# Count the length of a string with special chars in Javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping

So, I have a string like this

```
"v\xfb\"lgs\"kvjfywmut\x9cr"
```

and I want to find out the size of it, in Javascript. The thing is that if I copy it to console, the console will unescape the whole string. Will transform it to:

```
"vû"lgs"kvjfywmutr"
```

#### I don't want this to happen. Any tips/tricks?

Comment: The length of that string is 18, you can't count the "escaping" ?

Comment: *"The thing is that if I copy it to console, the console will unescape the whole string. Will transform it to:"* No, it won't. It will correctly determine that the 18 characters in the string are `vû"lgs"kvjfywmutr`. The backslashes aren't characters in the string, they're part of an escape sequence defining characters in the string.

Comment: The length of the first string is what I'm interested in. @adeneo

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, but I don't want that. :) I want to count all the chars.

Comment: But you **are** counting all the characters, the rest is escaping, and it can't be counted.

Comment: Add your expected output in the question !

Comment: @Venkatraman 25 for the first string and 18 for the 2nd one.

Comment: Issue is with UTF-8 characters

Comment: @Venkatraman: ***All*** characters are (potentially) UTF-8 characters. And UTF-16. And UTF-32. The transformation formats are just different ways of writing the same Unicode characters.

Comment: I just realized this question was form December of 2015. I'm working through the 2015 Advent of Code puzzles now too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the number of *source characters* (including the escape characters), there's no programmatic way to determine that, you'd have to do it by looking at the source code and counting.

The reason there's no way to do that programatically that once it's a string, it's a string, and there are many, many, many different ways the same string can be written using escape sequences.

For instance, these all define the same string:

```
var s1 = "v\xfb\"lgs\"kvjfywmut\x9cr";
var s2 = 'v\xfb"lgs"kvjfywmut\x9cr';
var s3 = "\x76\xfb\"lgs\"k\x76jfywmut\x9cr";
```

...and yet as you can see, the number of source characters differs.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I thought it was a way to determine the source characters in one way or another. :)

Comment: @Matei: Nope, there's no way other than examining the source code. Once it's a string, it's a string, nothing in the string contains hidden information saying what escape sequences were used to produce it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not "the correct" answer, but I was researching this same question and came up with a workaround solution. If you save the string in a text file and use fetch to read the file, you can count the length of a string including escape characters and outer quotes.

Assuming you have the string in a file named "strings.txt":

```js
fetch("strings.txt") // Connect to the URL Endpoint
        .then( // and then
          response => response.text() // take the response file
            .then( // and then...
              data => { // Do something with the data
                // if the file is only one line
                console.log(data.split('\n')[0].length); // 28 for your string

                // If the file has multiple lines                                   
                data.split('\n').forEach(v => console.log(v.length));
                    // 28, 27, 34 for T.J. Crowder's strings
                
              }
            )
        )
```